# Subselect in WHERE or FROM clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have wondered about general performance of a query if specific subselect (subquery) is located in `WHERE` or `FROM` clause. I didn't find sufficient explanation which way is better. Are there some rules how we should apply subselect in this kind of queries?

I prepared following example

**Query FROM**

```
SELECT name 
FROM users a 
  JOIN (SELECT user_id, AVG(score) as score
               FROM scores GROUP BY user_id
            ) b ON a.id=b.user_id 
  WHERE b.score > 15;
```

**Query WHERE**

```
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE 
  (SELECT AVG(score) as score
     FROM scores WHERE scores.user_id=users.id GROUP BY user_id
  ) > 15;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(30));
  
CREATE TABLE scores (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT,
  score INT);
  
INSERT INTO users(name)
  VALUES ('John'), ('Max'), ('Dan'), ('Alex');
  
INSERT INTO scores(user_id, score)
  VALUES
  (1, 20),
  (1, 19),
  (2, 15),
  (2, 10),
  (3, 20),
  (3, 18),
  (4, 13),
  (4, 16),
  (4, 15);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Have you compared explain/execution plans?

Comment: Usually mysql, but does it depend on dbms?

Comment: Different products have different optimization tricks.

Comment: Try running both queries and choose the one that works best on your system and your data.

Comment: Because of `WHERE b.score...`, `LEFT` is not relevant.  Please remove it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, so I should check performance of every new query? Isn't it possible that one of way is better in more cases?

Comment: @Tajni . . . There are general rules.  And I think that under many circumstances the correlated subquery will be faster.  But I can also think of exceptions to that.  You are talking about improving performance specifically on your data and your system; for that, you should test.

Comment: @Tajni - (to echo Gordon's point).  Increase the number of rows in your table to a few thousand, then test the many versions listed in the Answers here.  Then, please report back to us on what timings you got.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, `scores` needs `INDEX(user_id, score)` for performance.

It is hard to predict which will run faster.

There are times when a query *similar to* the first formulation is excellent.  This is because it goes off an focuses on `b` and efficiently calculates all the AVGs all at once.  Then it reaches over to the other table for the final info.

Let's tweak the second version slightly by adding some other test in the `WHERE` clause.  Now the second one might be faster.

This may be even better:

```
SELECT name 
    FROM ( SELECT user_id      -- Don't fetch AVG if not needed
               FROM scores GROUP BY user_id
               HAVING  AVG(score) > 15;      -- Note
         ) b
    JOIN users a  ON a.id = b.user_id
```

(The swapping of FROM and JOIN is not an optimization; it is just to show what order the Optimizer will perform the steps.)

In some other situations, `EXISTS( SELECT ... )` is beneficial.  (But I don't see such in your case.

Your question was about *general* optimization.  I'm trying to emphasize that there is no *general* answer.

Comment: I thought that in second query computes AVG for every user separately so it should be slower. But then I read that some DBMS optimize this kind of query to compute all of it at once and I wonder where is the edge of this trick. Thank you. I thought it's question with simple answer. Just one needs to know exactly how MySQL works underlay.

Comment: @Tajni - Some simple questions have simple answers; some don't.  Since MySQL is continually evolving, some answers change over time.  Subqueries did not exist in MySQL 4.0 (2 decades ago).  5.6 added some significant performance enhancements in this area.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this request is faster than what you give above, as it has no subqueries.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
JOIN scores s 
  ON (s.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY s.user_id
HAVING AVG(s.score) > 15
```

You can see it on this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b050f9/16
it shows the execution time of the next 3 Select queries:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users a 
  JOIN (SELECT user_id, AVG(score) as score
               FROM scores GROUP BY user_id
            ) b ON a.id=b.user_id 
  WHERE b.score > 15;
  
SELECT name 
FROM users 
WHERE 
  (SELECT AVG(score) as score
     FROM scores WHERE scores.user_id=users.id GROUP BY user_id
  ) > 15;

SELECT u.name
FROM users u
JOIN scores s 
  ON (s.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY s.user_id
HAVING AVG(s.score) > 15
```